# Windows Explorer Search does not find anything on Pictures, Documents, Downloads folders after manually moving them

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, search

Search in C:\Users\Komninos\Downloads not showing any results in Windows Explorer.

The quick search is not working for Downloads, Pictures, Documents folders, which are the folders I moved from D:\Users\Komninos\ to C:\Users\Komninos\ last week. I used TerraCopy the first time because D drive was slowly dying and I wanted to copy first and then move the Windows Location for the Downloads, Pictures, Documents folders.

Search works in other folders in C:\Users\Komninos\ for example  C:\Users\Komninos\Desktop
I tried disabling Indexing and enabling it, still no search on those folders I moved.

Strangely the quick search works on the old drive location (I still have a copy of folders there).
Rebuild index did not help.

If I move the folders to another location (using the normal Windows special Folders Move button and Apply), for example G:\Users\Komninos\Pictures then Search works again.
If I move it back to C:\Users\Komninos\Pictures then Search doesn't work.

Even if I move it to C:\Pictures the Search still does not work.

So it's like C: drive does not want to search Pictures, Documents, Downloads anywhere on it, but it does search other folders just fine. And these folders are able to be Searched when I put them on other drives.

Also I noticed that if I go to C:\Users\Komninos\Downloads through the Network (I have Shared them) on the same computer, then I can search their contents in Windows Explorer.

This is wrinkling my brain.

Comment: You have several sentences that seem to be missing key words. Please read through the entire question and resolve any grammatical mistakes you might have made. In detail explain how you are moving these key user profile folders?

Comment: *How* were those folders moved? Using Explorer's *Properties*, in *Location* tab?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Location in folder Properties to move them back and forth now to various locations to test it. It works on all other drives but C:
Yet other folders in C, have Search work fine.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks I fixed up the wording and syntax a bit. Hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new directory to your search index locations, like so:

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: More info is needed in question before that answer is applicable. **How** were those folders moved?

Comment: Included Locations it has Internet Explorer History , Start Menu , Users
When I go to Modify, it has selected C:\Pictures and C:\Users 
Excluded are AppData; AppData; MicrosoftEdgeBackups
It doesn't seem to update properly

Comment: Hmm I noticed also the Music Folder has this issue, I don't think I moved it ever.
As a test I moved it now to D: and I had the Indexing Options open, and it appeared in Included Locations! Search working. When I put it back to default location it goes away from the list. I try Modify and it has a checkmark, but seems Modify is bugged